# Highlight values in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a database with rankings from three different methods. Note that some methods have similar values, for example for the first alternative we have two values equal to 1 and another with a value equal to 29. Therefore, I would like to know if there is any way to highlight the repeated values for the same line, who knows how to leave it in red or in another way of highlighting.

Can you help me with this?

```
result<-structure(list(n = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
         12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
         28, 29), M1 = c(29L, 1L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 21L, 
         22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
         8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L), M2 = c(1, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 
        24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 15, 12, 19, 18, 17, 16, 14, 13, 11, 10, 9, 
       8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2), M3 = c(1L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 
       20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-29L))

> result
    n M1 M2 M3
1   1 29  1  1
2   2  1 29 29
3   3 28 28 28
4   4 27 27 27
5   5 25 26 25
6   6 26 25 26
7   7 24 24 24
8   8 20 23 20
9   9 21 22 21
10 10 22 21 22
11 11 23 20 23
12 12 15 15 15
13 13 12 12 12
14 14 17 19 17
15 15 18 18 18
16 16 19 17 19
17 17 16 16 16
18 18 13 14 13
19 19 14 13 14
20 20  5 11  5
21 21  6 10  6
22 22  7  9  7
23 23  8  8  8
24 24  9  7  9
25 25 10  6 10
26 26 11  5 11
27 27  4  4  4
28 28  2  3  2
29 29  3  2  3
```

Comment: You would have to define a custom `print` method taking advantage of the `crayon` package, which allows you to add color and other formatting to the text R console (only in RStudio). Quite a lot of work. It would be much easier to create a set of flag columns that parallel your data columns. Would that meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jdobres! I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors are only available in the RStudio console through the `crayon` package, so you would need to write a whole custom print method, which is a fair bit of work. Instead, you could use the **tidyverse** packages to create a set of flag columns that make it easier to track the duplications:

```
library(tidyverse)

output <- result %>%
  pivot_longer(M1:M3) %>% 
  group_by(n, value) %>% 
  mutate(T_F = ifelse(n() > 1, 'T', 'F')) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(value, T_F), names_glue = '{name}_{.value}')

colnames(output) <- gsub('_value', '', colnames(output))

       n    M1    M2    M3 M1_T_F M2_T_F M3_T_F
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
 1     1    29     1     1 F      T      T     
 2     2     1    29    29 F      T      T     
 3     3    28    28    28 T      T      T     
 4     4    27    27    27 T      T      T     
 5     5    25    26    25 T      F      T     
 6     6    26    25    26 T      F      T     
 7     7    24    24    24 T      T      T     
 8     8    20    23    20 T      F      T     
 9     9    21    22    21 T      F      T     
10    10    22    21    22 T      F      T     
# … with 19 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think the way you did it, it's much better to check equal values. I just wish it could be adjusted the names, ie, not to be `value_M1`, leaving just `M1`. That goes for others. And in case of `is_dupe_M1`, leave `M1 (T/F)`

Comment: Column names with spaces, parentheses, and slashes are not recommended, but I've reformatted the result to be closer to what you want. If this works for you, please mark as correct, and optionally, upvote.